# Multiple annotations not showing (Xcode mapview)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, annotations, android-mapview

```
[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSArray *name = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Marina Bay Sands", @"Sentosa", @"Singapore Polytechnic",nil];
NSArray *description = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Got casino!!", @"Got Universal Studio Singapore!!", @"Best polytechnic in Singapore!",nil];    

self.mapAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

//Set coordinates for pin
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = (double)1.2822463547298561;
location.longitude = (double) 103.85830879211426;
MapPin *mapPin = [[MapPin alloc] init];
[mapPin setCoordinate:location];
[mapPin setName: [name objectAtIndex:0]];
[mapPin setDescription:[description objectAtIndex:0]];
[self.mapAnnotations addObject:mapPin];

location.latitude = (double) 1.249404;
location.longitude = (double) 103.830321;
[mapPin setCoordinate:location];
[mapPin setName: [name objectAtIndex:1]];
[mapPin setDescription:[description objectAtIndex:1]];
[self.mapAnnotations addObject:mapPin];

location.latitude = (double) 1.309976;
location.longitude = (double) 103.775921;
[mapPin setCoordinate:location];
[mapPin setName: [name objectAtIndex:2]];
[mapPin setDescription:[description objectAtIndex:2]];
[self.mapAnnotations addObject:mapPin];

[self.mapView addAnnotations:self.mapAnnotations];

self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
[self location];
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Hi, rather new to Xcode programming and this are my codes in viewDidLoad. I'm trying to show multiple annotations and this is just to try out. But from this codes, I can only show 1 annotation and it is the last object I added into **mapAnnotations** array.

The only way I could get it to work was to initialize **mapPin1** and **mapPin2**, instead of using **mapPin** for all, for the other two annotations that I want to create. But this way it seems very inefficient (correct me if I'm wrong) and moreover, I have hundreds of data to add in. Can't possibly hardcode them.

Could someone help me with this?

Thank You =)

Answer (score 4):

I have added comments to your code that show what is *really* happening.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSArray *name = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Marina Bay Sands", @"Sentosa", @"Singapore 
    Polytechnic",nil];
NSArray *description = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Got casino!!", @"Got Universal Studio 
    Singapore!!", @"Best polytechnic in Singapore!",nil];    

self.mapAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

//here you create the properties of the pin the first time
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = (double)1.2822463547298561;
location.longitude = (double) 103.85830879211426;

//here you create the pin
MapPin *mapPin = [[MapPin alloc] init];

//now you set its properties
[mapPin setCoordinate:location];
[mapPin setName: [name objectAtIndex:0]];
[mapPin setDescription:[description objectAtIndex:0]];
//now you add it to the array
[self.mapAnnotations addObject:mapPin];

//now you are changing the properties of `mapPin`
location.latitude = (double) 1.249404;
location.longitude = (double) 103.830321;
[mapPin setCoordinate:location];
[mapPin setName: [name objectAtIndex:1]];
[mapPin setDescription:[description objectAtIndex:1]];

//the problem with adding mapPin again here is that you are adding
//the same object again, just with different properties, so
//your array still only has one object in it, `mapPin`, but with its updated properties
[self.mapAnnotations addObject:mapPin];

//you change the properties again here
location.latitude = (double) 1.309976;
location.longitude = (double) 103.775921;
[mapPin setCoordinate:location];
[mapPin setName: [name objectAtIndex:2]];
[mapPin setDescription:[description objectAtIndex:2]];

//and the same phenomenon I previously described happens again here
[self.mapAnnotations addObject:mapPin];

[self.mapView addAnnotations:self.mapAnnotations];

self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
[self location];
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

If you don't want to create new mapPins each time when you add them to the array, try this for every time you add the pin to the array:

Instead of

```
[self.mapAnnotations addObject:mapPin];
```

try

```
[self.mapAnnotations addObject:[[mapPin copy] autorelease]];
```

This will add a copy of your modified mapPin, instead of pointing to the same space in memory where the original one sits.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as such!

Answer (score 3):

You are creating one `mapPin` and adding the same object repeatedly.  You need to `alloc/init` a new annotation object for each annotation you wish to add to your map.

Answer (score 0):

For a clue try

```
int howManyAreThere = [self.mapAnnotations count];
```

after your 3 adds and breakpoint it to see what is actually happening.

Although NSMutableArray handles duplicates it does not copy the object you pass it. **It's smarter than that**.

Answer (score 0):

take all the lat long in the array and use below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrListing count]; i++) {


            List *obj = [arrList objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"Title %@  long:%@  Lat:%@",obj.Title,obj.log,obj.lat);

            CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;

            annotationCoord.latitude = [obj.lat floatValue];
            annotationCoord.longitude = [obj.log floatValue];

            MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
            annotationPoint.title = obj.Title;
            annotationPoint.subtitle = obj.log;
            [mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
        }
```